# Как поднять базу данных в Travis CI

Tags: база-данных, git, postgresql, travis

Как поднять базу с таблицами в Travis CI?
Базу вроде бы поднял, но как добавить таблицы?

`.travis.yml`:

```
before_script: psql -c 'create database test;' -U postgres
services: postgresql
addons: 9.4"
language: java
sudo: false
script: mvn clean verify
```

Comment: Nак же, как вы создали БД. Вообще по-хорошему вам надо внутрь приложения встраивать liquibase и вызывать при запуске/

Comment: Можно подробнее как это "Nак же, как вы создали БД"?

Comment: `before_script: psql -c 'create table ( ... );' -U postgres`

Comment: The command "psql -c 'CREATE TABLE public.contacts ( id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('contacts_id_seq'::regclass), name character varying, CONSTRAINT contacts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ' -U postgres" failed and exited with 1 during . Увы не работает!

Comment: это не "не работает", это вы апострофы не заэкранировали